# icomoon is not working on server but working on localhost

Tags: html, css

My folder structure is

index.php

css --> master.css

plugins--> icommon --> style.css

in master.css i am using @import url('../plugins/icomoon/style.css');

Icomoon fonts is working well in localhost but not on server

Comment: Please check the browser's dev tools(`F12`) and check that the css is loaded properly

Comment: Hello. I tried to read your question.  But it's not working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use Absolute path. For example:

```
http://my-web.example.com/my-section/plugins/icomoon/style.css
```